# Remove icons from system tray on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, system-tray

I have installed the extension Topicons and I want to remove the icons that I don't need like the orange skype icon because I have an extension for skype as you can see in this image

[image]

I have searched and tried some solutions but nothing seems to work.

If you are having trouble understanding what I want

[image]

I want to be able to remove icons that I don't want from the system tray on the bottom left corner.

Comment: There's nothing on the picture.

Comment: You cant see the two skype icons next to each other?

Comment: Oh, i see it. Try to rightclick the orange one and work it out yourself.

Comment: Thats all you need the extension Topicons takes the system tray and places it on top i want to know how can i remove an icon like skype from the system tray.

Comment: This is without the Topicons extension http://i.imgur.com/8b8wQQ8.jpg bottom left i dont need the skype icon

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.
You can tweak the settings too.

https://github.com/phocean/TopIcons-plus

You install it as a browser extension [from here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/)